# Is it possible to make magento use another user database?

Tags: magento2, database

If a website has an thousands of users registered and the credentia is stored one user database (one account) and we are installing a new store (magento). Is it possible to make magento use the existing user database so as to allow users to use the existing account to use magento?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that **user database means user data**.

Magento has own feature `where a website user account can be shared on other websites` if that ALL the websites are on  **create from one single MYSQL DATABASE**.

So, you have to go to admin>Store>Configuration>Customer>Customer Configuration.

Then go to tab `Account Sharing Options`.

Make `Share Customer Accounts` field value to **GLObal**.

[image]

After that changes, you have to do Reindex https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is not about sharing magento's user data, but rather making magento share user log in info from another database or table in the server. Imagine, installing magento on an existing website with thousands of registered users already.